# Does the string replace method use regex?

Tags: java

Until now, I thought that the `replace` method does not use regex; yet looking inside the `String` class, I see there is a Pattern compiled just as in `replaceAll`

The only difference I see is that the `compile` method has a flag `LITERAL` set.

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
        return Pattern.compile(target.toString(), Pattern.LITERAL)
                       .matcher(this)
                       .replaceAll(Matcher.quoteReplacement(replacement.toString()));
}
```

So my question is:

If I am doing intensive string replacement (e.g., thousands) using the `replace` method inside a for loop, should I cache the pattern and use its matcher to replace?

Currently I use

```java
private static final Pattern patternContainsC = Pattern.compile("(~C)|(\\[C])");
```

to speed up a few loops that use `replaceAll` method from the `String` class.

Comment: Why don't you just make a bench for like 1 billion replace ? :)

Comment: I have already that on the tool I must work on, I was told by a more senior developer to cache the pattern for `replaceAll` after he done some profiling on it.
Yet `replace` also seems to use regex inside it's implementation. And I am having a dilemma with my mentor if I should cache the Pattern also for the `replace` cases inside the for loops

Comment: I think Gremi64 is suggesting that you benchmark *`string.replace(term, repl)` vs `compiledPattern.matcher(term).replaceFirst(repl)`* to find which is more performant... something like that

Comment: Yes, caching the pattern will definitely faster than the normal operation.

Comment: Take a look on StringUtils#replace from Apache Commons Lang, their implementation is not regex based

Comment: I’m not sure which version of Java you’re looking at, but String.replace does not use regular expressions at all as of Java 9.  So any optimization you do will eventually be meaningless.

Comment: OpenJDK 14 still does not use any regular expressions for `replace`. Would be silly, if they would ever replace the current version with a less performant one.

Answer (score 0):

1. `String.replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement)` DOES use regular expression in *older* JDKs:

- [JDK 7, lines 2213..2230](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2213)
- [JDK 8, lines 2213..2228](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2213)

2. Starting from Java 9, `String.replace` DOES NOT compile `target` into regular expression:

- [JDK 9: lines 2166..2200](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/d966fc5a7be5/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#l2166)
- [JDK 11: lines 2129..2163](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/String.java#L2129):

```java
   /**
     * Replaces each substring of this string that matches the literal target
     * sequence with the specified literal replacement sequence. The
     * replacement proceeds from the beginning of the string to the end, for
     * example, replacing "aa" with "b" in the string "aaa" will result in
     * "ba" rather than "ab".
     *
     * @param  target The sequence of char values to be replaced
     * @param  replacement The replacement sequence of char values
     * @return  The resulting string
     * @since 1.5
     */
    public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
        String tgtStr = target.toString();
        String replStr = replacement.toString();
        int j = indexOf(tgtStr);
        if (j < 0) {
            return this;
        }
        int tgtLen = tgtStr.length();
        int tgtLen1 = Math.max(tgtLen, 1);
        int thisLen = length();

        int newLenHint = thisLen - tgtLen + replStr.length();
        if (newLenHint < 0) {
            throw new OutOfMemoryError();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newLenHint);
        int i = 0;
        do {
            sb.append(this, i, j).append(replStr);
            i = j + tgtLen;
        } while (j < thisLen && (j = indexOf(tgtStr, j + tgtLen1)) > 0);
        return sb.append(this, i, thisLen).toString();
    }
```

3. Method `String.replaceAll` compiles its own pattern from the target.

Then, if *the same* string pattern is applied to multiple strings, it is reasonable to cache the pattern and use `Matcher`'s `replaceAll` method.

```java
// this pattern checks if string contains '~C' or '[C]'
private static final Pattern patternContainsC = Pattern.compile("(~C)|(\\[C])");

public static String replaceSpecialC(String src, String replacement) {
    if (null == src || src.isEmpty()) {
        return src;
    }
    return patternContainsC.matcher(src).replaceAll(replacement);
}
```